# PHP simple html dom find element after of element

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser for my project..

How i can find element after of current element?

Ex:

```
<h2 class="block-title">Block A</h2>
<div class"block-content">Block A content ...</div>
<h2 class="block-title">Block B</h2>
<div class"block-content">Block B content ...</div>
<h2 class="block-title">Block C</h2>
<div class"block-content">Block C content ...</div>
```

Expected results ex

```
"Block A" => "Block A content ...",
"Block B" => "Block B content ...",
"Block C" => "Block C content ..."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`next_sibling()`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_traverse) to selecting element after selector.

```
$html->find('h2[class=block-title]')->next_sibling()->innertext()
```